# Визуализация графа с покраской рёбер

Tags: python, matplotlib, networkx

Использую библиотеки networkx и matplotlib.
У меня есть словарь с цветами, которыми нужно покрасить рёбра графа:

```
colors_of_edges = {(2, 4): 'red', (4, 5): 'green', (1, 2): 'green', (2, 3): 'gold', (3, 4): 'blue', (1, 5): 'red'}
```

Создавался данный словарь с помощью алгоритма покраски вершин графа. На вход подавался граф, имеющий вид:

```
L.add_nodes_from([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
L.add_edges_from([(1, 2), (1, 5), (2, 4), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5)])
```

Преобразовывался в рёберный граф, на котором выполнялся алгоритм покраски вершин:

```
> G.nodes()
[(2, 4), (4, 5), (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (1, 5)]
> G.edges()
[((2, 4), (4, 5)), ((2, 4), (3, 4)), ((2, 4), (1, 2)), ((2, 4), (2, 3)), ((4, 5), (1, 5)), ((4, 5), (3, 4)), ((1, 2), (2, 3)), ((1, 2), (1, 5)), ((2, 3), (3, 4))]
```

Как можно нарисовать такой граф с помощью библиотеки matplotlib? При этом покрасив рёбра изначального графа так, как указано в словаре

Comment: неплохо было бы привести в вопросе код для создания соответствующего графа ;)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62139935/5741205

Comment: @MaxU не подходит этот вариант. Здесь цвета заданы с помощью метода `.add_edges`, у меня же цвета для рёбер подбирает сама программа, занося их все в словарь. Может быть, я что-то не до конца осознала в ответе по ссылке...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Модуль networkx.

Методы DiGraph(), draw_networkx_nodes(), draw_networkx_labels(),add_edges_from().

В add_edges_from() есть параметр color, задающий цвет ребра. А в draw_networkx_edges есть параметр edge_color)

Рисуем графы, какие вам надо. Да, и естественно, используется совместно с matplotlib.